Can anyone discover where the bug in this code, when I choose to not play again it get in an infinite loop?
import random

random_num = random.randint(1, 100)

count = 1
while True:
    try:
        num = int(input("Guess the number? "))

        if num == random_num:
            print("Congrates! you guessed it.")
            print("Tried:", count, "times")

            play = input("Do you want to play again Y/N? ")
            if play.lower() in ['n', 'no']:
                quit()

            elif play.lower() in ['y', 'yes']:
                random_num = random.randint(1, 100)
                count = 1

            else:
                quit()

        elif num > random_num:
            print("Not yet, smaller.")
        elif num < random_num:
            print("Not yet, Greater.")
        else:
            quit()
        count += 1
    except:
        print("Oops! please enter a valid number.")

When I run this code it runs normally. But when I finish the game and choose to not play again it stuck in infinite loop
When I run the good and choose n or no it stuck in infinite loop
Guess the number? Oops! please enter a valid number.

forever, but what I expecting is to finish the game and end the program.

instead of quit() use break to exit the loop

Don't use bare exceptions. Catch the exception you expect instead so the program can crash for cases you haven't considered. My guess is that quit throws a SystemExit exception.

You can find the error yourself if you remove the try statement and the except block.

@abdulshafi99 "Don't use bare exceptions" is the most important thing to take from this question. Be as specific as possible with your exceptions or you will catch things you didn't intend to, like in this case. Even except Exception: would work, but you can be even more specific than that. quit() causes a BaseException, specifically SystemExit and you probably never want to catch those.

As @Cincinnatus commented, using a break statement to exit the loop should solve this issue. Alternatively, you can try establishing a variable to maintain the current "running" status of your loop. Here is your code adjusted to use this pattern:
import random

random_num = random.randint(1, 100)

count = 1
running = True
while running:
    try:
        num = int(input("Guess the number? "))

        if num == random_num:
            print("Congrates! you guessed it.")
            print("Tried:", count, "times")

            play = input("Do you want to play again Y/N? ")
            if play.lower() in ['n', 'no']:
                running = False

            elif play.lower() in ['y', 'yes']:
                random_num = random.randint(1, 100)
                count = 1

            else:
                running = False

        elif num > random_num:
            print("Not yet, smaller.")
        elif num < random_num:
            print("Not yet, Greater.")
        else:
            running = False
        count += 1
    except:
        print("Oops! please enter a valid number.")

